# Mesh is getting black on change

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have written a small code, which is mooving vertices down on mouse click. The problem is in that mesh on change is getting black (only in some places).

Here's the code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MinerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public MeshFilter filter;
    public MeshCollider col;

    public GameObject Player;

    public float mineSpeed = 200;

    Mesh mesh;
    Vector3[] vertices;

    void Update()
    {


        filter = transform.parent.GetComponent<PlayerGravity>().mesh;
        mesh = filter.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;
        vertices = mesh.vertices;

        Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward * 2);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray))
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
            {

                int index = Mathf.RoundToInt(ClosestIndexToPoint(ray));
                vertices[index] += (-Player.transform.eulerAngles) * Time.deltaTime * mineSpeed;
                mesh.vertices = vertices;

                mesh.RecalculateBounds();
                mesh.RecalculateNormals();

                Color[] colors = new Color[mesh.vertices.Length];
                colors[index] = Color.red;
                mesh.SetColors(colors);
                //col.sharedMesh = mesh;
            }
        }
    }

    public float ClosestIndexToPoint(Ray ray)
    {

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit))
        {
            Mesh m = hit.transform.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;
            col = hit.transform.GetComponent<MeshCollider>();

            int[] tri = new int[3] {

             m.triangles[hit.triangleIndex * 3 + 0],
             m.triangles[hit.triangleIndex * 3 + 1],
             m.triangles[hit.triangleIndex * 3 + 2],

         };

            float closestDistance = Vector3.Distance(m.vertices[tri[0]], hit.point);
            int closestVertexIndex = tri[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < tri.Length; i++)
            {
                float dist = Vector3.Distance(m.vertices[tri[i]], hit.point);
                if (dist < closestDistance)
                {
                    closestDistance = dist;
                    closestVertexIndex = tri[i];
                }
            }

            return closestVertexIndex;
        }
        else
            return -1;
    }
```

I don't think the problem is in color, as i've tried to apply the teture on it.

[image: Mesh on change]
[image: Here's the mesh itself]

[image: Colored mesh]

About code:
It throws a ray, and if it hits any mesh, it is calling func "ClosestIndexToPoint". It returns value of type float. This function gets the triangle a ray hits, and then finds the closest vertecs to it. Then it just mooves it down (or the rotation of our Player object, cause a have a non - flat mesh).

Comment: looks like a problem with the normals. probably wrong calculation because of your vertex movement.